# IBM MobileFirst 7.1.0 WL.Device.getID changes on the same device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio, mobilefirst-runtime

mfp -v 7.1.0.00.20160401-2108
wladm -version 7.1.0.00.20160323-1606

WL.Device.getId sometimes returns different id on the same device with app reinstallation or update from Store.
It happens both on Android and iPhone.
It happens only when app is reinstalled (updated), or switched from debug to release.
When installed the ID is persistent.
We use LDAP server where DeviceID is login value. So when ID changes I see the completely new login value from same device.

What could be reason of this behavior?

Comment: We need to ask for a bit more information please:
  - Is this an upgraded system or a new installation?
  - What database are you using?  Cloudant, DB2, etc.
  - You're saying that the behavior is inconsistent.  Have you seen a pattern as to the relative time the app has been on the devices with the problem?
  - Are you seeing an error in the server or client logs?

One thing I'd suggest you do is to look directly at the records in your database for one of the devices that is giving you incorrect results and see if that device has more than one record in the database.

Comment: I upgraded server recently with new iFix. We use DB2. The change happens on reinstall or app update. When I switch from developer (debug) to release, or when when updating from Store. We use LDAP server where DeviceId is the Login value. And when change happens I see completely new ID from the same device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background information:
The device id generated by the MobileFirst SDK for android is stored in KeyStore file, and in iOS in keychain file. Both of these are not 100% guaranteed to keep the original stored values in cases such as application uninstallation/reinstallation/upgrade, end-user changing the device security settings or doing a factory reset.

For these reasons it is not a recommended pattern to use the `WL.Device.getId` value as the principal login value.

The recommended pattern is to use a  unique user identity such as email, or username. Please note that future version of MFP may discontinue support for the `WL.Device.getId` API method.